# Null Pointer Exception in setMessage() of Custom Android Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

I am trying to extend ProgressDialog class to create my custom dialog. When i try to execute the following implementation. It is giving Null Pointer Exception in the setmessage() call

Can Somebody please explain how to go about it?

```
private class SubProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

    Textview tvdialogtext;
    public SubProgressDialog(Context context) {

        super(context);
    }


    @Override
    public void setMessage(CharSequence message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tvdialogtext.setText(message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.loadingdialog);
        tvdialogtext = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvloading);
        Typeface ttf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getContext()
                .getAssets(), "calibriitalic.ttf");
        ImageView ivloading = (ImageView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.ivloading);
        ivloading.setBackgroundResource(R.animator.loading);
        AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) ivloading
                .getBackground();
        anim.start();
        anim.setVisible(true,true );

        tvdialogtext.setTypeface(ttf);

        tvdialogtext.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        tvdialogtext.setShadowLayer(25f, 0, 0, Color.WHITE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        /** dismiss the progress bar and clean up here **/
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        running = false;
        finish();
        help.comeinfromleft();
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
 09-28 21:17:48.154: E/AndroidRuntime(27745): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-28 21:17:48.154: E/AndroidRuntime(27745):   at           m   sfs  com.anshul.guessthegaana.OnePlayerArena$SubProgressDialog.setMessage(OnePlayerArena.java:1552 )
 09-28 21:17:48.154: E/AndroidRuntime(27745):   at       com.anshul.guessthegaana.OnePlayerArena$GetSongsFromServer.onPreExecute(OnePlayerArena.java:1     191)
 09-28 21:17:48.154: E/AndroidRuntime(27745):   at           android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
 09-28 21:17:48.154: E/AndroidRuntime(27745):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
 09-28 21:17:48.154: E/AndroidRuntime(27745):   at com.anshul.guessthegaana.OnePlayerArena.onCreate(OnePlayerArena.java:247)
 09-28 21:17:48.154: E/AndroidRuntime(27745):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
 09-28 21:17:48.154: E/AndroidRuntime(27745):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
 09-28 21:17:48.154: E/AndroidRuntime(27745):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
```

Initializing Call

```
        dialog = new SubProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Preparing the Game");

        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
tvdialogtext = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvloading);
```

If your `tvDialogText` is defined in your R.layout.loadingdialog just use:

```
tvdialogtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvloading);
```

If not, show us where are you initialising `dialog`.

Hope it helps

Comment: The call to Oncreate is working fine. The NPE is in setmessage(). Still gave your solution a try no help. Adding the inintializing code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Figured it out

The Problem was that the AsyncTask which was calling the Dialog was called on ONCREATE of activity so the dialog was not instantiated.

So a workaround

Put up a Default message in the dialog to be used when the dialog is called from Async task called in Oncreate of activity

The setmessage should work for later instances

Working code

```
private class SubProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

    TextView tvdialogtext;

    public SubProgressDialog(Context context) {

        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessage(CharSequence message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.setMessage(message);

        if (tvdialogtext != null) {

            tvdialogtext.setText(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.loadingdialog);


        tvdialogtext.setTypeface(ttf);

         // Your Default Text
        tvdialogtext.setText("Preparing The Game");


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        /** dismiss the progress bar and clean up here **/
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        running = false;
        finish();
        help.comeinfromleft();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Method to solve the problem is to just create your ProgressDialog into your onPreExecute() method and Declare it Globally.

Like this:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
```